# RSpec No example found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For some reason, RSpec is not recognizing assertions in one of my spec files - but runs the print statement around it.

To start the spec test, on the terminal:

```
rspec spec/lib/slots_scheduler_spec.rb
```

Part of the spec file that asserts... (is part of a loop)

```
print "#{slots_result[0].date} #{slot.date}\n"
slots_result[0].date.should == slot.date
```

And what I see on the console...

```
....
2012-11-18 2012-11-11
2012-11-25 2012-11-11
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00005 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

If something is wrong, I expect some other message than '0 examples, 0 failures'. Why are my tests ignored like this?

Comment: OK - I actually figured out why... I didn't wrap the test around "it ... do". This is embarrassing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You Haven't Defined an Example Group

Your code, as posted above, has no example groups. [Example groups](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/basic-structure) require a *describe* or *context* block, and a *specify* or *it* block for each test in order to work.

Your print statements work because they are valid Ruby. However, the RSpec DSL requires more from you before it will result in an actual test being performed.